# how to clear session automatically after a single event in django

Tags: django, session

I am developing a e-commerce project using django.It is a image based project where user can download image after subscription.

There is a single image download subscription package available to the user where user can only download an image for a single time.My home page have an image thumbnail.

If any user wants to download any image ,he can click on the selected image and then will take the user in the image detail page of the clicked image with download button option.If he subscribed,he can download the image.

Though its a single image download subscription,so user can only download a single image.but the problem is,after a single download,if the user don't leave the page,he is able to download the same image for an unlimited time.I want to restrict it but i have no idea how to do this in django.

After a single download,redirecting the user to the home page or my image thumbnail page can be solution,but i don't think it will be great idea.Because there will be a possibility to disconnection of internet or something right after the download event which will create situation where may be the user can not complete the download action.

so i want to settle the user in the image download page after a single download and immidietly wants to clear the session  and restrict him to download the same image for unlimited time.

Can it be possible to clear the session after a single download,i think if i can clear the session after a single download or an event or whatever you say,then the user can not download the image for twice.Is it possible to clear the current session after an event in django?

Comment: You clear the session then the the user login state lost. I don't think this is a good idea

Comment: then do you any other idea?,somehow i have to restrict the user to download the image more then a single time.

Comment: checking permissions before download may be work `if user.has_downloaded_image=true:`